# Easy way to upload a screenshot (from clipboard) through a browser form

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, webforms, screenshot

i am pretty sure, that i've seen such a feature on a website somewhere in the web.

i want to give the user a form, where he can input some data and attach the current clipboard content (very likely a screenshot)  to the form and then submit it as an image file.

after all, i don't want the user to go through all the hassle: take a screenshot, open his favorite image processing app, paste the screenshot, save it as a file, then go to my form to click a browse button and eventually search for the saved file.

there has to be an easier method, with all the ajax-jquery-web2.0-stuff.

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should clarify if you mean just a particular OS or all OSs as it will likely affect the answer.

Comment: you are right. i think windows would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Jira does this using a signed Java applet.  I'd suspect if it were possible to due it in pure JavaScript, that Google Docs would have this feature, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment on Chris Beaman's answer, so I'm giving this as a standalone.)

Uploadscreenshot.com does do this, and they use a Java applet to do so. I don't think it's possible via any generic form element that I'm aware of.